# Dialogflow @sys.email entity is not identifying emails

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

In my intent I am expecting the user to provide his/her email address.

I tried using **@sys.email** entity to identify the email from training phrases, but it is not identifying the email address.

What could be the issue ? When I searched the web I saw similar question being asked in some Google Groups, but could not find the answer.

**EDIT:**

Here is a screenshot the intent page showing Training Phrases and Actions and Parameter:

[image]

Other than the email's in screen shot I've tried with several other email id's, work and personal, It did not identify any of them.

Comment: can you give some examples on what is being recognized and what is not so that people can recreate the problem and help you.

Comment: Well the only thing I need to identify in that intent is the mail id provided. So the phrase can be just the mail id like ***'example@gmail.com'*** or it can be something like ***'My mail id is example@gmail.com'***. In both cases I need the identify the value ***example@gmail.com***. Do you want me to add a screenshot?

Comment: yes, please provide screenshots which email address are it is able to recognize and which are not. i tried few just now with @sys.email and DialogFlow was able to recognize all of them. there were few mis-recognition as well.

Comment: I've added screenshot to the question. For me it did not identify any of the mail id's I provided

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for the screenshot, I now understand your problem and was able to recreate it.

At first, I tried similar approach and added some user phrases but did not tag them with `@sys.email`. DialogFlow was also not able to tag them itself, and hence it is not able to extract emails as well.

[image]

After that, I manually tagged the email address from the user phrases with `@sys.email` and then it worked fine.

[image]

So, tag the email addresses in the training phrases with the entity `@sys.email` and try again. It should work.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah that seems to work. Thanks. I did try this way before must've missed something, was getting whole string as email that time. It work's now although I am worried it might not identify email in some cases.

Comment: yes, it might miss... to be sure, i think you should put a regex check as well in the webhook call.

Comment: Yeah, will be doing that

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to extract the user details like email, username, and phone number, etc. You need to use the "Action and Parameters" option in Dialogflow.

After adding the training user phrases in the Dialogflow intent, Dialogflow will tag the email part with @sys.email. Sometimes DialogFlow would not be able to tag them itself. So you may need to drag and manually tag the email address from the user phrases with @sys.email

If you are using any tools as interface then you can use JSON to update it. Please refer to this [article](https://docs.kommunicate.io/docs/bot-setup#update-user-detail) for more details and the steps