# Dialogflow email address from speech

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, speech-to-text

Does anyone have any suggestions for obtaining a user’s email address through speech? Written is quite straight forward as email addresses follow a pattern to some degree, but using speech is quite difficult. Is it best to simply ask the user to read out the characters one by one?

Answer (score 1):

Dialogflow provides [System entites](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/system-entities) for most common user inputs.
You can use **sys.email** entity for your purpose and then use it in your fulfillment.

[image: email entity demo]

Getting the above email address in your webhook fulfillment :

```
app.intent('getEmail', (conv, params) => {

  const userMail = params.email;
// remember to use the same variable name that you defined as
// Parameter name in your intent to access in params

 });
```

Just make sure to manually select the email address in training phrases if dialogflow does not automatically detect it. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53494250/dialogflow-sys-email-entity-is-not-identifying-emails) for more assistance.

Hope that helps!

Comment: it is recommended to use regex check in the webhook as well to validate the email address, as sometimes detected email address is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Even today, 5 years after the question, it's still not straight forward. Most speech to text services, including OpenAI's Whisper or Google Cloud's speech-to-text API will not easily recognize email addresses and present them formatted correctly. If not post-processed, you will see results like 'john at doe.com' (where the @-sign is not properly formatted and the elements are separated by spaces) or 'J O H N at D O E .com' when the user is trying to spell the address.
I recommend using some AI as post-processing where you train a model to recognize/classify the few different cases that can happen (it's not so many; the 2 I showed and then some spelling errors with common domain names) and solve each case by reformatting according to the case (in both examples I gave: replace 'at' with '@' and remove the spaces). That works fairly well and I get up to 90% recognition.

To get to an even higher level, I added a similarity check on (and correction to) the 200 most common domain names in my country, which pushed up the level to around 95%.

If the email address you'd want to recognize might be included in a known list (ie registered customers) you could add a [custom class](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/adaptation-model#custom_classes).

Another challenge is speed. If you ask a user in real time to provide their email address (for a registration, track order-command or complaint for example), you'd probably want to provide immediate feedback on how you recognized the address. I needed a local STT model and a local classification model to deliver the required speed for in-store situations.

Comment: Gave up on this project a long time ago. Yes, best bet is to train a letter classifier from audio. These services only get you 80% of the way there...